# Should a foreign key be created on the parent table or child table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-keys

What's the difference? If I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Account (Id int NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE Customer (AccountId int NOT NULL)
```

And I want a foreign key linking the two, which of the following should I do and why?

Option 1:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK 
  ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Accounts_Customers] FOREIGN KEY([AccountId])
  REFERENCES [dbo].[Account] ([Id])
```

Option 2:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account]  WITH CHECK 
  ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Accounts_Customers] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
  REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id])
```

Comment: I usually put it on the one table that can't live without the other (when that applies). But it will depend on whatever makes your queries simpler, whatever makes more sense from a data conceptual standpoint... and those two whatevers may be opposite, even.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on context. Does every customer have a client? Which one is the parent? It seems like an Account has multiple Customers, in which case the reference belongs on the Customer table.

Now, that said, please call the entities `CustomerID` and `AccountID` everywhere. It may seem redundant on the primary table but the name should be consistent throughout the model.

Comment: One thousand percent agreement about the naming. You should not use ID as the field name for a PK - always prefix with the entity name. This is especially important when using ORMs that use convention based mapping as this is often how they expect the model to look. The downside is that you have to qualify your objects when writing joins, but `a)` you should do this anyway and `b)` with an ORM you probably wouldn't write much/any T-SQL

Comment: If you were to use Rails & rails-inspired frameworks that is not true. In that case when id is a primary key it's just 'id' like `customers.id` - it's obvious enough. When referenced as a foreign_key you do `accounts.customer_id ` like so .

Answer (score 5):

I would use a foreign key from the child to the parent. The tell tale question is: what happens if you need to delete one of the entities?

Comment: In this case, if I delete a customer, I don't want it to cascade to accounts, but if I delete an account, it should cascade to customers.

Comment: So account can live without customer but customer can not live with account. Thus customer should point to account and not the other way round. --> Option 1

Comment: @scottm you should write logic in your DELETE procedure that handles the cascade. I'm not a big fan of - and don't really trust - the ON CASCADE options currently available in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

A FK (foreign key) tells the DBMS that values for subrows for a column list must appear elsewhere as values for subrows for a column list. Whenever that happens (and it isn't already implied by other declartions) declare the FK. If in addtion you want a CASCADE action applied to the referenced table on a change to the referencing table, declare that.

(There's nothing special about CASCADE that it couldn't be offered for non-FK situations. It just comes up frequently with FKs, and there's an explicit graph of FKs by which to reasonably restrict their interactions.)

If there is a [FK cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41886468/3404097) then you will need to use triggers. Your decision of which constraint(s) are enforced declaratively & which by trigger should consider the graph of (desired) constraints.