# Relational database design - "cyclic" graphs

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, cycle

In relational database design, should one worry about one (or more) "cyclic graphs" posing problems?

(Simplified) E.g., tables

T1(**T1_Id**, ...)
T2(**T2_Id**, T1_Id_Fk, ...)
T3(**T1_Id_Fk, T2_Id_Fk**, ..)

Primary keys are bolded.

Rows in T1 have a double role. A T1 row r1 can be in relationship T3 with a row r2 in T2, but it can also be a parent row for a (possibly the same) row r2' in T2. These two relationships are orthogonal.

I came up with something like this:

T1_Base(**T1_Id**, ...)
T1_Child1(**T1_C1_Id**, ...)
T1_Child2(**T1_C2_Id**, ...)
T2(**T2_Id**, T1_C1_Id_Fk, ...)
T3(**T1_C2_Id_Fk, T2_Id_Fk**, ...)

where we have one-to-one relationships between T1_Base and T1_Child1 and T1_Child2, respectively, to eliminate some of the possible cascading issues described here [Relational database design cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002024/relational-database-design-cycle), but I still get a cycle.

Should I even be worried about this in a context where every FK is defined with ON CASCADE NO ACTION?

Comment: What cycles exactly do you think these designs have?

Comment: @cloud I see no cycle in your original tables. Functional dependencies and foreign key constraints are both directional, but neither set forms a cycle in your case. Note also that in relational databases, we don't relate rows to other rows (that's the old network data model), rather we relate values or domains. That's why we say tables represent relations.

Comment: A FK can have multiple columns. You don't make clear what your FKs are. Please edit your question. It is better to just give a DDL-like statement about what is referencing what. (Although you don't have to declare a direct reference that is a consequence of a chain of other ones.) PS "orthogonal" here is unclear. Please write out what you mean.

Comment: You don't make clear how your two designs are connected, eg how one is a view of the other, ie how you have rearranged the first into the second. Also, besides it not being clear what the constraints on your first design *are* (naming is not enough to give FKs), it's not clear whether your text is trying to *repeat* that or say what they *should* be.

Answer (score 2):

A FK (foreign key) constraint is *directed*. A FK declaration is a statement that subrow values for a table & column list appear as subrow values for some other "referenced" table & column list. When people talk about FK "cycles" they mean cycles of FK references all put head to tail.

You don't appear to have any such cycles here.

(*Tables* represent application relationships/associations. FK constraints are often called "relationships" although they are actually just statements about tables that are true in every database state. Although every FK has an associated query-expressible table representing an associated relationship/association.)

There's no logical problem with such cycles. When that happens, the tables all have exactly the same set of subrow values for those superkey/UNIQUE column lists. (Indeed there is a 2-way constraint between every pair of tables.) In the simple case where all the FK columns lists are the same (same names, same order) and all non-FK columns are different, it means that instead of the separate tables you could use just the one table that is their join. Otherwise, after suitable column renamings you could still use just one table.

But many DBMSs can't handle FK reference cycles being declared, because FK declarations do double duty for cascades on update, and the DBMS designers haven't offered a facility for the designer to say what order cascades should happen in when there's a cycle. So if you don't want a one-table design then you are forced drop the cycle by dropping one of the declarative FK constraints. Although you can enforce the constraint via a trigger, which is the only general constraint facility available in SQL DBMSs.

PS Since your first design probably has `T3 (T1_Id_Fk, T2_Id_Fk) references T2 (T1_Id_Fk, T2_Id)` and `T2 (T1_Id_Fk) references T1(T1_Id)`, your 2nd design is probably not properly constraining.

Comment: Very useful! Thanks!